# Is the term "deceleration" ambiguous? Does it refer to negative acceleration, or is it something else entirely?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, acceleration, velocity, speed

What does that term truly mean? Sometimes it confuses me what exactly it refers to.

Comment: The question is pretty hard to understand. What graphs? Can we see them?

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are talking about, getting a picture would be very helpful.  I might have an idea what you're asking, but it's hard to tell right now.

Comment: I'm still confused what you're trying to compare, can you provide some sort of drawing of what these graphs look like?  I really don't understand the motion you're trying to compare.

Comment: "*seems like the exact same graph of that of constant increasing deceleration, but that isn't the case.*" Isn't this the case?? Why not? Are they different, since you say that? Would be better if we could see the actual graphs you have looked at and made this conclusion on. **De**celeration is indeed just another name for negative acceleration, so the graphs should certainly be equal. *Deceleration* is a more used term in every-talk, I believe, while in physics you don't really hear anyone use it.

Comment: If they are standard graphs it shouldn't be difficult to provide an example to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Well picturing your situation all I get are [these](http://i.imgur.com/g74Zk9i.jpg) graphs, which don't look the same at all.  I do not understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I  thought the convention was, acceleration is by default, an increase in velocity, and what you call deceleration is normally termed negative acceleration.

Comment: @Countto10 Yes, that is the usual convention.

Comment: Using the word "deceleration" almost universally causes confusion. It has two possible interpretation (acceleration of a negative sign or acceleration such that speed is decreasing) which are not the same, and there is no universal (or even widespread) agreement on which should be the meaning used. Consequently there is good reason to avoid the word in technical discussions.

Comment: Worse, I can offer strong criticism of both possible meanings. Take "acceleration of a negative sign"; it's very clear in one-dimensions, but is $\vec{a} = (+2, -3) \,\mathrm{m/s}$ a deceleration under that rule? Why or why not? However, "such that speed is decreasing" has it's own problem: while all (Galilean) inertial observers can agree on a object's acceleration they don't all agree on it's current speed so an particular acceleration might cause speed to increase for some observer, and decrease for others (and—allowing for instantaneous evaluation—not change at all for a third group).

Comment: My 5Cents: To get it intuitively go by train, close your eyes, spin yourself as long as you don't know the direction of the direction the train moves and sit down. At some time the train will accelerate, you will feel this acceleration but it will be impossible for you to know the reason, which are brake, acceleration or turn to the left or right.

Comment: @close voters The question is hopefully fixed now and much more clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same. It is up to you to choose the positive direction for displacement.

Some people consider the displacement along the negative y-direction as positive. This coordinate system is useful while solving objects which are falling under gravity.

Some people consider the displacement along the positive y-direction as positive. This convention is useful while solving problems where the object starts moving upwards initially.

The term deceleration is generally used to indicate that the speed is reducing. Deceleration is indeed the negative of acceleration. However, you can have negative values of acceleration and declaration. You can say that a car which is accelerating at $5 m s^{-2}$ is decelerating at $-5 ms^{-2}$.